# Storing a piece of the string for later use in replacement

Tags: php, regex, search, replace

Not sure if the subject was clear, hard to describe, easy to show:

I need to convert this:

```
$text = 'Bunch of text %img_Green %img_Red and some more text here';
```

to this:

```
$text = 'Bunch of text <img src="/assets/images/Green.gif" alt="Green" /> <img src="/assets/images/Red.gif" alt="Red" /> and some more text here';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, fixed the code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be

```
$text = preg_replace('/%img_(\w+)/', '<img src="/assets/images/\1.jpg" alt="\1"/>', $text);
```

check out the [preg_replace doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on how this is working

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Justin!